# Why is the turtle not showing up when called?

Tags: python

When running my pyw/turtle code, the turtle is not showing up, I have tried everything I know, any help?
I put the "player = Turtle()" at the beginning, however it still isn't working.
Is this a computer issue or just my code is broken

```
from turtle import *
import random
player_win = 0
dragon_win = 0
player_level = 0
player_xp = 0
while True:
    def forward():
        global player
        player.forward(20)
    def backward():
        global player
        player.backward(20)
    def left():
        global player
        player.left(20)
    def right():
        global player
        player.right(20)
    def fight():
        global player, dragon, ph, dh
        print("You have encountered a wild dragon!")
        fight_yes_or_no = input("Do you want to fight this dragon??")
        if fight_yes_or_no == "yes":
            ph = 500
            dh = 500
            while ph > 0 and dh > 0:
                if dh > 0:
                    print("Dragon attacks!")
                    damage_dealt = random.randint(0, 50)
                    print("Dragon caused", damage_dealt, "damage")
                    player -= damage_dealt
                if ph > 0:
                    print("Player attacks!")
                    damage_dealt = random.randint(0, 50)
                    print("Player caused", damage_dealt, "damage")
                    dh -= damage_dealt
                if dh == 0:
                    print("Player wins!")
                    print("You have earned 20 xp!")
                    player_xp +=20
                    if player_xp == 100:
                        player_level +=1
                        player_xp = 0
                        print("You have reached level", player_level)
                if ph == 0:
                    print("dragon wins!")
                    print("You have lost 20 xp!")
                    player_xp -=20
                    if player_xp == 0:
                        player_level -=1
                        player_xp = 0
                        print("You have reached level", player_level)
                    if player_level > 0:
                        print("You died!")
                        quit()
                    
        if fight_yes_or_no == "no":
            print("Ok")

player = Turtle()
player.home()
screen = Screen()
player.penup()
player.speed(0)
screen.onkey(forward, "W")
screen.onkey(backward, "S")
screen.onkey(left, "A")
screen.onkey(right, "D")
screen.listen()
dragon = Turtle()
dragon.shape("turtle")
dragon.penup()
dragon.goto(30, 40)
dragon.speed(0)
while ph >=0 and dh>=0:
    if player.distance(dragon) < 20:
        fight()
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a `while True:` loop without any kind of break. How do you expect the code after that loop to be executed?

Also, you are using event driven programming, so you should move the code into functions:

```
from turtle import *
import random

player_level = 0
player_xp = 0

def forward():
    player.forward(20)
    fight()
def backward():
    player.backward(20)
    fight()
def left():
    player.left(20)
    fight()
def right():
    player.right(20)
    fight()

def fight():
    global player_level, player_xp

    # If they are not close enough to fight, do nothing
    if player.distance(dragon) >= 20:
        return

    print("You have encountered a wild dragon!")
    fight_yes_or_no = input("Do you want to fight this dragon??")
    if fight_yes_or_no == "YES":
        ph = 500
        dh = 500
        while ph > 0 and dh > 0:
            if dh > 0:
                print("Dragon attacks!")
                damage_dealt = random.randint(0, 50)
                print("Dragon caused", damage_dealt, "damage")
                ph -= damage_dealt
            if ph > 0:
                print("Player attacks!")
                damage_dealt = random.randint(0, 50)
                print("Player caused", damage_dealt, "damage")
                dh -= damage_dealt
            if dh == 0:
                print("Player wins!")
                print("You have earned 20 xp!")
                player_xp +=20
                if player_xp == 100:
                    player_level +=1
                    player_xp = 0
                    print("You have reached level", player_level)
            if ph == 0:
                print("dragon wins!")
                print("You have lost 20 xp!")
                player_xp -=20
                if player_xp == 0:
                    player_level -=1
                    player_xp = 0
                    print("You have reached level", player_level)
            if player_level <= 0:
                print("You died!")
                bye()

    else:
        print("Ok")

player = Turtle()
player.home()
screen = Screen()
player.penup()
player.speed(0)
screen.onkey(forward, "W")
screen.onkey(backward, "S")
screen.onkey(left, "A")
screen.onkey(right, "D")
screen.listen()
dragon = Turtle()
dragon.shape("turtle")
dragon.penup()
dragon.goto(30, 40)
dragon.speed(0)

screen.mainloop()
```

Comment: TYSM it worked!:)